# WPF Bindings won't update unless I recreate the entire list?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, mvvm, binding

**Background:**

I have a `List<T>` in my ViewModel defined as...

```
private List<FooBar> _fooBars;

public List<FooBar> FooBars
{
    get { return _fooBars; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _fooBars) return;
        _fooBars = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FooBars");
    }
}
```

`FooBar` is defined as...

```
public class FooBar
{
    public string FooBarProperty { get; set; }
    // more properties here
}
```

Meanwhile, I have a `GridView` that binds to this list.

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding FooBars}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView
            <GridViewColumn
                Header="Foo Bar Prop"
                DisplayMemberBinding={Binding FooBarProperty} />
            <!--more columns here-->
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I run my app and all this works great. My FooBarProperties fill as expected.

**The Problem:**

In response to some user action. I *edit* one of the `FooBar` objects in `FooBars`, and call `OnPropertyChanged()` to let WPF know I want the bindings to update.

```
FooBars[2].FooBarProperty = "Some new text here";
OnProperChanged("FooBars"); // WPF is not listening to this :(
```

Only one problem: this completely doesn't work. The `GridView` never udpates.

**A Workaround:**

After much head scratching (and table banging and swearing), I came up with this replacement for the above:

```
FooBars[2].FooBarProperty = "Some new text here";
FooBars = FooBars.Select(fb => fb).ToList(); // this works but why is it necessary?
```

Works like a charm, but why do I need to do this?

NOTE: I tried switching from `List<FooBar>` to `ObservableCollection<FooBar>`, but that made absolutely no difference.

**My Questions:**

Very simply, why do I need this crazy code that basically copies the list into itself to get my bindings to update?

Is there a better way to force an update?

Thanks.

**EDIT -- The Final Solution:**

Thanks to @Botz3000's answer below, I switched `FooBars` back to `ObservableCollection<FooBar>`, and I modified `FooBar` so it implements `INotifyChanged`. Everything works as it's supposed to and no weird list copying required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not changing the object that is stored in the `ObservableCollection` itself, but rather a property of it, then the CollectionChanged event won't be triggered.

Your `FooBarProperty` needs a `PropertyChanged("FooBarProperty")`, too. Since the list items bind to this property, they'll need notifications for that.